# How do tools like Speedfan detect the CPU temperature?

Tags: cpu, speedfan, sensors

There are some applications which claim to be able to detect the temperature of various components inside your PC, for example: [Speedfan](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php&ei=dMRpTq_CC6miiAfx4b3KBA&usg=AFQjCNHjPjmFuQJwp3IUFKLphybQl1SlRg). How do they detect the temperature without using any external tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are sensors, spread all over your pc. They depend on the hardware you use, but almost every motherboard has a thermal sensor at the cpu socket. So all what those tools do is polling those sensors for information. You can do that on your own with a little bit of programming, for example by using WMI.